# calling parent's method with parameter from nested class in python

Tags: python

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "abc"
        self.child = self.Child()

    def run(self):
        self.child.task()

    def output(self, param1):
        print(param1)

    class Child(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.text = "cde"

        def task(self):
            Parent.output(Parent, self.text)  # I get the warning for this line


parent = Parent()
parent.run()
```

Code above works as expected but IntelliJ IDEA is warning me with this message
"An instance of nested_classes.Parent expected, not the class itself"
Is there something wrong with my code?
Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend posting your code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as well. There are many points that can be addressed there.

Comment: If you follow out ZachGates' comment, make sure that you don't post it until it is working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access your `output` method (which is an instance method) as a class method. The message is coming up because the first parameter `self` is the instance object, so you passing the `class` as the first parameter will actually change the content of what `self` should have as an instance object. That is what the message is trying to tell you. So, what you actually *should* be doing is call the method as an instance method:

```
Parent().output(self.text)
```

Based on what you were doing, if you check the `repr` and contents of the object of `self` inside the `output` method, you get this:

```
def output(self, param1):
    print(repr(self))
    print(dir(self))
    print(param1)
```

Using this method of calling: `Parent.output(Parent, self.text)`

```
<class '__main__.Parent'>
[
    'Child', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', 
    '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', 
    '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', 
    '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', 
    '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'output', 'run'
]
```

As you can see, you do not have an `instance` of `Parent` in your `self`.

Now, if you call it as an instance method: `Parent().output(self.text)`

```
<__main__.Parent object at 0x1021c6320>
[
    'Child', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__',
    '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', 
    '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', 
    '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__',
    '__weakref__', 'child', 'output', 'run', 'text'
]
```

As you can see, you now have a `Parent` object and if you look at the contents of the object, you would have what you would expect from your instance properties.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You did not declare output as a class method so it expects to be called by an instance of Parent.